# Why isn't my recv getting any data

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Here's my function's I'm using to do the send() and recv()'ing.

```
bool Socket::send( const std::string s ) const noexcept {
  int status = ::send ( m_sock, s.c_str(), s.size(), MSG_NOSIGNAL );

  if(status == -1)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

int Socket::recv( std::string& s ) const noexcept {
  char buf [ MAXRECV + 1 ];
  s = "";

  memset ( buf, 0, MAXRECV + 1 );

  int status = ::recv ( m_sock, buf, MAXRECV, 0 );

  if ( status == -1 ) {
    std::cout << "status == -1   errno == " << errno << "  in Socket::recv\n";
    return 0;
  }
  else if ( status == 0 ) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    s = buf;
    return status;
  }
}
```

The server accepts a client then calls send() with a test message.

```
std::cout << server.send(s) << std::endl;
```

Which is always returning false (writing 0 to cout). The client recv()'s by doing the following.

```
std::string s;
  int i = 0;
  while (s.empty()) {
    i = k.read(s);
  }
```

And it never leaves this loop. Both are set blocking by calling this function with false sent as the parameter.

```
void Socket::set_non_blocking ( const bool b ) noexcept {
  int opts;

  opts = fcntl(m_sock, F_GETFL);

  if(opts < 0)
    return;

  if( b )
    opts = ( opts | O_NONBLOCK );
  else
    opts = ( opts & ~O_NONBLOCK );

  fcntl( m_sock, F_SETFL,opts );
}
```

Comment: What does the `send` function's documentation say you should do when it returns -1 to find out what went wrong? Also, why does your receive function ignore errors? How can you possibly figure out what it's doing if it ignores errors?

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee that what you recieve is a null-terminated string, which makes a construct like `s = buf;` likely to produce undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Error message is "Broken Pipe" on the send. "why does your receive function ignore errors?"... not totally sure what you mean by that, it prints the errorno if there is an error. Error checking beyond simple things like that is all I yet know how to do.

Comment: @user2183336 what is 'k', what is 'read'? can you share a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example?